# Is minimizing softmax cross entropy with two labels equivalent to minimizing sigmoid binary cross entropy with 1 label?

Tags: neural-networks, softmax

Is using a sigmoid at the end of a neural network with 1 label equivalent to using a softmax with 2 labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The most intuitive explanation is this: what is the difference between inferring the probabilities $p$ and $q$, where $p + q = 1$, and inferring just $p$?

---

Here's a more detailed explanation, if you're interested. Note that when the number of classes $K=2$, the softmax is equal to

$$softmax_1 = \frac{e^{s_1}}{e^{s_1} + e^{s_2}} = \frac{1}{1 + e^{s_2-s_1}} = \sigma(s_1 - s_2)$$

And likewise for the second class.

Hence, for a neural network, the last linear layer of which outputs the vector $s = (s_1, s_2)$ just before the softmax layer, there exists an equivalent network that has the same layers, but computes $s_2-s_1$ and then outputs the sigmoid of the result. But since $s_2-s_1$ is a linear operation, two consecutive linear layers can be squashed into one linear layer with a single output, i.e. a sigmoid network.

The same reasoning is true vice versa: a sigmoid neural network can be transformed into an equivalent softmax network by adding one more neuron with zero weights.

That's why optimizing one network is equivalent to optimizing the other.

Comment: I see so the loss function are mathematically equivalent. But does that mean the optimization are equally easy (perhaps for common optimization algorithm only)? It seems like there is less parameter if use sigmoid.